# Apache2 + VirtualEnv IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv

I am having trouble getting apache to serve my site via virtualenv (and virtualenvwrapper). I tried following the walkthrough [here](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/). Of note, I am using Ubuntu Server v13.10 which I've read doesn't have native support for Apache v2.2 yet, thus in the walkthrough I was not able to install apache2.2-common. However, I don't think that is the issue as the apache error logs are saying there is a permissions problem.

In my setup the virtual environment lives in a non-root user's home directory, while the apache server runs as root (I think this is normal). I have tried to trace the permissions using `namei` and I've made sure to `chmod +rw` to the path as `root`. Any ideas?

```
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:37.639031 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8771:tid 140338386122624] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5+ configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:37.639144 2014] [core:notice] [pid 8771:tid 140338386122624] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456622 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742] mod_wsgi (pid=8775): Target WSGI script '/var/www/www.mysite.org/index.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456735 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742] mod_wsgi (pid=8775): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/www.mysite.org/index.wsgi'.
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456782 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456830 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742]   File "/var/www/www.mysite.org/index.wsgi", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456918 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
[Thu Mar 06 14:16:53.456971 2014] [:error] [pid 8775:tid 140338291197696] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX:50742] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/nrUser/Envs/mysite/bin/activate_this.py'
(mysite)root:~# namei -m /home/nrUser/Envs/mysite/bin/activate_this.py
f: /home/nrUser/Envs/mysite/bin/activate_this.py
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x home
 drw-r--r-- nrUser
 drwxrwxr-x Envs
 drwxrwxr-x mysite
 drwxrwxr-x bin
 -rwxrwxr-x activate_this.py
```

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu: I disagree. As long as the apache user is able to read, and possibly execute, the files, the owner shouldn't be the problem. However, to be able to access a file, you need the x bit on ALL directories above it. It seems like the x bits are missing from /home/nrUser.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm is right. I removed my wrong comment. Thanks.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm: You have provided the correct answer if you wish to formally answer the question you can get some points. I think in another tutorial it had me set the permissions to 644. I believe this removed the execute bit. I didn't think the directory required the execute bit, but it does in order to read the directory contents. This was confirmed when I logged out and was unable to load any of my profile settings! But it's fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to access the files, the apache owner needs at least the x bits on all directories above your files, and the r bit to the files themselves. Your nrUser directory is missing the x bits; `chmod 755 /home/nrUser` should fix your problem.

Comment: is it safe to do this on a public web server or will break security?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Apache user/group needs permissions to read the directories. Try applying `chown` to your `mysite` directory, for example:
`sudo chown -R <user>:www-data mysite` <-- while in nrUser home directory

Restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart` and see if you can access your website.

Comment: Serakiel, you're right that apache needs permissions, but there are better ways than to use chown. Especially if you're hosting multiple web pages for multiple customers, you want different OS users, and you want the files to belong to the individual users. Granting access on group/others level is the right thing to do in this case.